# How can I reset a JTree?

Tags: java, swing, jtree

I'm currently working with JTree, more precisely with CheckBoxTree, an inherited class created by JIDE. I need to find a way to reset the tree, meaning :

- Clearing the selection
- Erasing the nodes

I tried unsetting the Tree variable, the treeModel, and refreshing the UI, but it doesn't works.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unsetting the variable alone won't help - all that will do is lose your copy of the reference to the JTree object.

What you need to do remove the reference the containing object holds to the JTree - I assume you have it some kind of GridContainer or Layout object - remove it from the parent ojbect and then call updateUI on that object.

Answer (score 1):

For erasing the nodes you should get the tree model and clear it or set a new tree model.

To clear the selection, call `clearSelection()` on the tree (note that `setModel(...)` already calls `clearSelection()` so if you want to do both together, just set a new model and repaint).

Answer (score 0):

Just rebuild the tree at the beginning of each iteration.

Something of this sort

```
RootNode=new CheckBoxTreeNode("root");
CheckBoxTree= new CheckBoxTree(RootNode);
```

would do the trick. No need to call updateUI. Hope this help.